# How to add ILoggerFactory to Startup dotnet core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, loggerfactory

I'm using dotnet core 3.1 and I want to add ILoggerFactory to startup constructor.

But I get an error:

> 'Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory' while attempting to
> activate 'Startup'.'

My configuration in Program.cs:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.AddConsole();
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should configure logging in the HTTP request pipeline(your Startup configure method).

eg.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
     //depending on what you use for logging 
   loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();
     //or
   loggerFactory.CreateLogger...
     ...
}
```

Comment: Isn't this incorrect, as the 2.2 dot net core spec specifies to do it in Program.CreateWebHostBuilder via "ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging)"?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

(bottom of the page)